# Get BioProject code of a GEO dataset

Tags: public-databases, data-download, geo

In publications the GEO code is usually shared and not the BioProject/study code.

I want to get the BioProject/Study Accession code of a GEO dataset (to later download the data from ENA).
I know that I can go to the website and see find it but I would like to automate the process.

[GEOquery](https://doi.org/doi:10.18129/B9.bioc.GEOquery) didn't provide it, and the data doesn't seem to be available via [the FTP](ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/README.txt).
Is there a programmatic way to obtain it?

Comment: This must be doable because it has an API here https://rdrr.io/bioc/GEOquery/api/ - which is exactly what is needed here

Comment: Can you please explain more about why going to the website is not good enough? For a single GEO dataset, it would be quicker and easier to use the website.

Comment: Because I want to download the files from multiple GEO datasets and match the data with other information. The background history is that my group currently do not have a local copy of some data which I know was published in a paper, that paper has several GEOs and I want to download them and find which samples are from the missing data. 
I think I identified the relevant one, but I might have missed it and I want to have a solution for the future (I think this will happen more :( )